# Haskell List Comprehension and Pattern Matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, list-comprehension

I'm looking for a function which gives me all matching numbers of a letter, for example `giveNumber "D" [("D", 5), ("A", 4) ("D", 25)] = [5,25]`

```
giveNumber :: String -> [(String, a)] -> [a]
giveNumber letter (x:xs) = [snd x | x <- xs | fst x == letter]
```

I get a parser error with that.

Comment: For future reference, it's always a good idea to post the error message that you get.  It lets others see the error you're getting, rather than just knowing that you have an error.

Comment: I just wanted to mention if you just have letters I would use `Char` instead of `String`, and in addition there is `Data.Map` worth looking into.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need pattern matching or list comprehensions, since I'd say this is easier with filter and map:

```
giveNumber :: (Eq a) => [(a, b)] -> [b]
giveNumber x ys = map snd $ filter ((== x) . fst) ys
```

Although you could do it with some minor adjustments to your code:

```
giveNumber letter xs = [snd x | x <- xs, fst x == letter]
```

This may make more sense to you, but either will be about the same in execution time.  What you were doing wrong was that you had a second `|` symbol in your comprehension where you needed a comma, and you didn't need to pattern match `(x:xs)` as an argument, since the `x <- xs` loops over all the `xs`.

Alternatively, you could do it even more simply as

```
giveNumber letter xs = [y | (x, y) <- xs, x == letter]
```

Of the three choices, this one is probably the most readable and easiest to understand, but I like the first one best because it's all from composing higher order functions and can be eta reduced to

```
giveNumber x = map snd . filter ((== x) . fst))
```

making the `ys` parameter implicit.

You may also be interested in the `lookup` function that is built in:

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

but this only looks up a single element, with the possibility for failure.

Comment: That eta reduction isn't quite right! Otherwise a great answer -- covers all the high points.

Comment: @DanielWagner Oh, you're right, I should have used `.` rather than `$`, thanks for catching that =)

Answer (score 6):

You have 2 little mistakes:

1) You miss a coma in `[("D", 5), ("A", 4) , ("D", 25)]`

2) in list comprehension you used `|` twice, not once

```
giveNumber letter xs = [snd x | x <- xs , fst x == letter]
```

You could write a bit prettier:

```
giveNumber letter xs = [y | (x,y) <- xs , x == letter]
```

By the way, this function is more general then `String -> [(String, a)] -> [a]` :

```
giveNumber :: Eq a => a -> [(a, t)] -> [t]
```

Comment: @msietrterc The last point there is very important.  Don't add any more constraints to a type signature than you absolutely have to.  Makes your code more reusable.